# Liferay: Transferring data from dynamic data list to web content

Tags: web, liferay, dynamic-data-list

We have it setup so users submit submissions to the dynamic data list and than if we want to approve and publish it we have to manually copy over all of the information. Is there an easier way to do this. Perhaps a feature that allows you to create web content from a data list? I should also mention that the web content has more fields than the dynamic data list for back end purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way that you could activate with just flipping a switch. However, an API based solution can be easily scripted. If you're working with workflow, you can even tie this to the state transition to being approved. You can also build a custom portlet or just a script that reads DDL and creates (or updates) web content articles.

While I'm stating that it's simple, it's a bit too much to just add to this answer as pseudocode. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the data in web-content, you can use Liferay's DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil class to read the data in Velocity template for your web content as explained [here](https://www.liferay.com/web/marcellus.tavares/blog/-/blogs/12150383). If you provide more information about your requirements then I can explore more possibilities.